# GNU make: how prevent '-include file.ext' from executing a rule the target of which is 'file.ext'?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Just to review the terminology, this is the structure of a makefile 'rule':

```
target:   dependencies ...
          commands
          ...
```

This is the makefile I've written:

```
CC = mpicc
SHAREDLIB = libfmd.so
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wno-unused-result -O3 -fopenmp
LFLAGS = -lm -fopenmp -lgsl -lgslcblas

OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

.PHONY: all shared clean
all: shared
shared: $(SHAREDLIB)
$(SHAREDLIB): depend.mk $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -shared -o $@ $(LFLAGS)
depend.mk: *.c *.h
    $(CC) -MM *.c > depend.mk
-include depend.mk
clean:
    rm -f *.o libfmd.so depend.mk
```

When the folder is clean, and I enter `make clean`, the following lines are shown:

```
mpicc -MM *.c > depend.mk
rm -f *.o libfmd.so depend.mk
```

It seems to me that `-include depend.mk` in addition to including `depend.mk`, executes the rule that `depend.mk` is its target. I'd like to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  See [How Makefiles are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) in the documentation.

There is no way to prevent this behavior: if there's a rule that creates an included makefile, make will always rebuild it if it's out of date, then re-invoke itself to read the latest version.

The question is, why do you want to avoid it?  Maybe if you explained the behavior you are actually looking for at a higher level we could help.  As you have it here it's possible for .o files to be created without any depend.mk file created, then a compile fails, you modify a header file to fix it, but since the depend.mk file doesn't exist when you re-run make the source files are not rebuilt properly.

If you want to get accurate handling of C/C++ dependencies with GCC you might take a look at [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Answer (score 1):

```
depend.mk: *.c *.h
    $(CC) -MM *.c > depend.mk
```

<s>FYI, this is wrong, as make doesn't support shell wildcards in a rule string. Although on a recipe line that could work as it gets expanded by the shell itself.</s>

> I'd like to stop this behavior

depend.mk is a prerequisite of the default target, so it is a target anyway.

Also, preprocessing into depend.mk is slow for large projects, so it totally makes sense either to switch to manually written dependencies, or use a recommended way to generate them, as @MadScientist suggested.

Comment: It is not true that make doesn't support shell wildcards in a rule string: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html says _The targets are file names, separated by spaces. Wildcard characters may be used_ and also _the prerequisites, which consist of file names separated by spaces. (Wildcards ... are allowed here too.)_